# Centralised Password Management Software

Tags: windows, mac-osx, access-control-list, password-management

Currently, the company I work for has nothing in the way of password management - everything is in a big excel spreadsheet that everyone has access to. Obviously this has a whole rash of issues attached to it, namely:

- Staff have access to passwords they shouldn't have/don't need.
- Anyone who can get access to a machine on the network can get full access to all the passwords.

So, I'm pushing for us to move to a new system....however, I don't have a whole lot of experience in this area, so I don't know what solution to suggest.

Essentially, I'm looking for some form of password management solution, where administrators can limit individual users to a limited subset of passwords, but while still having all the passwords in one (secure) place.

Assuming it's some form of server->client solution, it needs to have clients for both OS X and Windows (and ideally Linux, but not essential!)

If anyone has any recommendations, I'd love to hear them!

Thanks,

Liam

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are quite a few tools out there that you can take a look at for what you're requesting:

- [Managed Engines Password Manager](http://www.manageengine.com/products/passwordmanagerpro/)
- [Lastpass](https://lastpass.com/enterprise_overview.php)

My company was previously using a homebrewed PHP password manager, but we switched over to a commercial manager. I currently use Lastpass as my current personal password manager, but they also have an enterprise version which you can check out.

Answer (score 2):

Liam,

See if this former question will help:  https://serverfault.com/questions/119892/company-password-management

I've looked at the same idea in the past, but we always end up back with a password-protected spreadsheet on a secure area in Sharepoint for IT staff.

The one I really liked personally was Cyber-Ark http://www.cyber-ark.com/digital-vault-products/pim-suite/enterprise-password-vault/index.asp but it was just out of our price range.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for the link - I would upvote your answer, but I don't have the reputation!